# Why does my arraylist in java become empty by itself

Tags: java

I have a simple code. I am dividing a number by its smallest factor till I get 1. But for some reason my arraylist which stores the factors is getting empty.

```
long total = 0;
long current = 6;
total += current;
while(current > 1){
     ArrayList<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
     for(long j = 2; j<= Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(current)); j++){                
         if(current % j == 0){
           numbers.add(j);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(numbers);
     total += current / numbers.get(0);
     current = current / numbers.get(0);
 }
```

My answer should be 6 + 3 because 6/2(smallest factor) + 1 because 3/3(smallest factor).

My error is coming in total += current/numbers.get(0);

When I print the arraylist it shows [2,3] but then becomes empty. This is the compiler.

[image]

Comment: If your `if` condition doesn't match, then no number is added to the list. So it remains empty. Debug your code to find out, why.

Comment: If you instantiate a list in a while loop, it's normal that you get a new instance with 0 elements from time to time..

Comment: But at first there was [2,3[ then why did it become []

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `numbers = new ArrayList<>()` and start using the debugger.

Comment: Can you explain how

Comment: No, it depends on the IDE you are using. 9 out of 10 times its just clicking the debug button. Read a tutorial if you are unable to debug. It's a beginner practice you should familiarize yourself with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are instantiating the array list inside the while, it will be always empty if any if or the for condition are not matched

You can instantiate the array list before the while condition like below:

```
ArrayList<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); 
while(current > 1)
```